# Tensorflow mapping channels while keeping other dimension

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I am trying to map a set of activations X  of size `(?, 200, 300, 2000)`

to a representation `(?,  200, 300, 100)`.

For this I have a weight matrix W of size `(2000, 100)`. How can I achieve that each `(?, x1, y1, 2000)` is multiplied correctly? I tried tf.matmul and tf.tensordot but couldnt get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you (going with smaller shapes to speed up the computation):

```
X = np.ones(((5, 2, 3, 7)))
W = np.ones((X.shape[3], 10))
X_reshaped = tf.reshape(X, [-1, X.shape[3]])
# Shape: (30, 7)
y = tf.matmul(X_reshaped, W)
# Shape: (30, 10)
y_reshaped = tf.reshape(y, [-1, X.shape[1], X.shape[2], 10])
# Shape: (5, 2, 3, 10)
```